# How to get the file size in bytes in react-native-image-picker and also set the max file size

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how to get the exact file size in bytes in react-native-image-picker. I want to set the max limit for image size. It give file size as 1442255 but i want in bytes

```
onPaymentProofChange = () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      if(response.error) {
      } else {
           console.log("true",response)
        console.log("file size",response.fileSize)
      }

    });
  }
```

Comment: have you tried using a package for this? like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64)

Comment: I am used react-native-image-picker for choosing a image. but i dont use any package to calculate the size  of the image